# Do recurring Hosted Services require keep alive?

Tags: c#, .net-core, task, asp.net-core-hosted-services

I've created a hosted service that executes a recurring task in .Net-Core. 
(I'm using shared hosting so I don't have control over iis)

```
public class SchedulerService : IHostedService
{
    private readonly ILogger _logger;
    private Timer _timer;

    public SchedulerService(ILogger<SchedulerService> logger)
    {
        this._logger = logger;
    }

    public Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        this._timer = new Timer(ExecuteTask, null, TimeSpan.Zero,
            TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30));

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    private void ExecuteTask(object state)
    {
    }

    public Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        this._timer?.Change(Timeout.Infinite, 0);
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

I'd like to ensure that this task is always run.  But Hosted Service's are **NOT** [guaranteed to complete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51144048/net-core-hosted-services-guarenteed-to-complete) due to app-pool recycles etc.

I'm a bit confused on this notion.  I'm under the impression now that Hosted services are only run in the background after a request is made and once the app pool is recycled the background task is killed (e.g 90 second limit from the older version of .net)

**EDIT**

I tested this in my API and it seems to run continuously even hours after the last requests was made. Note: I tested this in IIS Express so that still doesn't guarantee behavior.

If this is the case, and no request are made to my site, can I still be guaranteed that my SchedulerService will run?

Or should I just have my scheduler service send a request every ~75 seconds to myself, to ensure that a new thread will restart the scheduler?

Comment: Does your task need to be a hosted service? If it needs to run on a guaranteed schedule you may be better off looking at an [azure function timer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-timer)

Comment: I'm not using azure

Comment: You can manually recycle the app pool and test this.

Comment: @HenkHolterman good point, but I'm not sure if that is the only cause for the hosted services to shut down.  That's just the only one I know of

Comment: IIS Express does not have an application pool, so you won't see a recycle. Try it with a full IIS.

Comment: @Stijn thanks,  I'll investigate

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you run your ASP.NET Core application in IIS ([not IIS Express](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53753802/do-recurring-hosted-services-require-keep-alive#comment94765207_53753802)):

- For your hosted service to start automatically, you need to set the **Start Mode** of the application pool to **Always Running**. See [Rick Strahl](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2013/oct/02/use-iis-application-initialization-for-keeping-aspnet-apps-alive) for more information.
- For your hosted service to keep running indefinitely, you need to set the **Idle Time-out** of the application pool to **0**.

If you run the application as a Windows Service, none of this is needed.

Also, for forward compatibility, make your hosted service inherit the [`BackgroundService`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.hosting.backgroundservice?view=aspnetcore-2.2) class and register it for dependency injection using `AddHostedService`.

AFAIK, using the [IIS in-process hosting model in .NET Core 2.2](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2019/Mar/16/ASPNET-Core-Hosting-on-IIS-with-ASPNET-Core-22) has no effect on this.

Comment: I do that it's working 2 or 3 hours but if i set timer every 24 hours it's not working. Could advice me